# Não estou conseguindo exbir um listView que usa um ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho uma classe principal que herda da Activity onde tenho minhas views, mas precisei criar uma outra classe que herda ArrayAdapter. Porém não estou conseguindo apresentar minha listView, o estranho é que quando pega um item da lista e imprimo funciona. Alguém pode dar um help? Agradeço desde já!

Este método está na minha classe que herda Activity. Este é o método para preencher a activity que não está mostrando nada.

```
//recebo um vetor de String com dados do banco
public void preencheListView(String[] paises) {

        lv = new ListView(this);
        //instancio aqui
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, paises);
        //aqui eu consigo imprimir um pais para teste, o que significa que o adapter está ok
        System.out.println("teste: "+adapter.getItem(1));
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        linearlayout.addView(lv);

    }
}
```

Esta é a minha classe que herda ArrayAdapter

```
public class ArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public Context ctx;
    public int rec;
    public String[] paises;



    public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] p) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, p);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.rec = resource;
        this.paises = p;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int getRec() {
        return rec;
    }

    public void setRec(int rec) {
        this.rec = rec;
    }

    public Context getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public void setCtx(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public String[] getPaises() {
        return paises;
    }

    public void setPaises(String[] paises) {
        this.paises = paises;
    }


}
```

Obs: Antes de eu criar a classe ArrayAdapter funcionava certinho, porém tive que criar a ArrayAdapter porque vou precisar usar o `getView()`.

Obs2: Coloquei um `adapter.getCount()` agora e descobri que o adapter está vazio mesmo, porém imprimo o item, com o `adapter.getItem(x);`

Obs3: Será que estou chamando a classe ArrayAdapter da maneira correta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no método

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
    }
```

Ele não deve retornar null, mas deve retornar uma `View` que será o item do seu `ListView`, então dentro do seu método `getView` faça o seguinte código:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Você deve implementar os métodos `add` e `getItem` também.
Desta forma:

```
@Override
public void add(String value) {
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}
```

> Não implementar os métodos também resolverá seu problema.
>   Caso você não precise implementar o método, ou não faça `@Override` ou chame sempre o código da super classe, desta forma: `super.METODO`

Comment: obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Valeu, fico feliz em poder lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Em seu adapter vi que você está retornando 0 no metodo getCount neste trecho do seu codigo:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Tente ao invés disso retornar o tamanho da sua Array de Strings assim:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return paises.length;
}
```

E também no método getItemId tem que retornar a posição que é mandada como parametro:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

Assim você consegue retornar o getCount do seu objeto corretamente e também retornar o Id de cada item que nada mais é do que a própria posição do item.